# Expected number of steps to absorbtion - Markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I want to calculate the expected number of steps (transitions) needed for absorbtion. So the transition probability matrix $P$ has exactly one (lets say it is the first one) column with a $1$ and the rest of that column $0$ as entries.

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & * & \cdots & * \\ 0 & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \vdots & & & \\ 0 & & & \end{bmatrix} \qquad s_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \\0 \\ \vdots \\  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

How can I now find the expected (*mean*) number of steps needed for the absorbtion for a given initial state $s_0$?

EDIT: An explicit example here:

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0.1 & 0.8 \\ 0 & 0.7 & 0.2  \\ 0 & 0.2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} 
\qquad s_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \implies s_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.8 \\ 0.2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \implies s_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0.82 \\ 0.14 \\ 0.04 \end{bmatrix} \ldots $

Comment: This is not a transition probability matrix.

Comment: The rows of a transition matrix must add to 1!

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that? (Perhaps I used the wrong words, since english is not my native language.) I mean the matrix where each entry $p_{ij}$ is the probability for getting from $j$ to $i$. So if you mulitply the initial vector with that matrix you get a new vector with a probability for each state (the distribution at that point of time). So the columns should add up to 1. (Right?)

Comment: But if that is so, your second column, as I can understand, has each entry 0. Then how can its elements add to 1? I think it is better, if you write down the matrix more explicitly.

Comment: @SomabhaMukherjee I hope I could make it clear now. $(P)_{1,3} = 0.8$ which the probability for the transition $\#3 \rightarrow \#1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We conventionally read row by row, but it appears that in your matrix, the columns add to 1 instead. 
I'll write your matrix like this and proceed:

\begin{align*}
  P = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0.2 & 0.8 \\ 
0.2 & 0.7 & 0.1  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

which is of the form

$$P=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
Q & R \\ \hline
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

and

\begin{align*}
  s_0 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

For the expected time to absorption, we need to calculate

$\left(I-Q\right)^{-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
1 
\end{pmatrix} \approx \left(\begin{array}{r}
1.92307692307692 \\
4.61538461538461
\end{array}\right)
$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am sorry for the confusion, as I had never proper education in probability theory I was not aware of this convention. (I think in linear algebra at least it is more common to use column vectors, thats why I wrote it down that way.)

Comment: You are welcome! I think I read about markov chains first from [this book](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf). You may find it interesting too! (I see that book has become popular from the returned search result for "matkov chain")

Comment: Oh thank you very much, was not able to read the whole thing right now but it seems to be written in a way even I can understand=)

Comment: Welcome again, have fun!

Answer (score 3):

Let $t_i$ denote the mean time to absorption at state $0$ starting from state $i$ then $t_0=0$, one is after $t_2$, and the usual one-step Markov property yields 
$$t_2=1+\frac15t_1,\qquad t_1=1+\frac7{10}t_1+\frac15t_2,$$ which is solved by
$$
t_2=\frac{25}{13}=1.923\ldots
$$
For $n+1$ states, one gets an $n\times n$ affine system whose solution $(t_i)$ describes the mean times to absorption at state $0$ starting from each state $i\ne0$.

Comment: Thank for you answer, these two equations just gave me more valuable insight in how to solve this!